# Why data fetch from factory is not avalaible in the view?

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling with an angularjs controller which not provide some data to the view and i don't understand why.

Here is the route config :

```
.when('/settings', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/settings.html',
                    controller: 'SettingsController',
                    access: {
                        authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.user]
                    }
```

I have a controller  :

```
jhipsterApp.controller('SettingsController', function ($scope, Account,Countries) {
        $scope.success = null;
        $scope.error = null;
        $scope.settingsAccount = Account.get();
        $scope.countries  = Countries.get();

        $scope.save = function () {
            $scope.success = null;
            $scope.error = null;
            $scope.errorEmailExists = null;
            Account.save($scope.settingsAccount,
                function (value, responseHeaders) {
                    $scope.error = null;
                    $scope.success = 'OK';
                    $scope.settingsAccount = Account.get();
                },
                function (httpResponse) {
                    if (httpResponse.status === 400 && httpResponse.data === "e-mail address already in use") {
                        $scope.errorEmailExists = "ERROR";
                    } else {
                        $scope.error = "ERROR";
                    }
                });
        };
    });
```

And factories :

```
jhipsterApp.factory('Account', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('app/rest/account', {}, {
        });
    });

jhipsterApp.factory('Countries', function ($resource,$http) {
   // return $resource('app/rest/countries', {}, { });
    return{
    get: function() {
        var promise = $http.get('app/rest/countries').then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
    }
});
```

Here is my view :

```
 {{settingsAccount}}//  {{countries}}
```

I want to display settingsAccount and countries retrieved by factories.
In the browser, i have the following results :

```
{"login":"user","password":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":"User","email":null,"langKey":"en","roles":["ROLE_USER"],"country":""}// {}
```

We can see settingsAccount is set but no countries. I don't understand why ?

When i check the F12 Chrome tools, i can see the both request made by factories :
[image: settingsAccount]
[image: countries]

Why countries data are not avalaible on the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your Countries.Get is returning a promise and not the array of countries (and is also asynchronous) you need to populate countries after the promise is completed.

```
Countries.get().then(function (countries) {
    $scope.countries = countries;
});
```